# check_path exception with SonataUserBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I did have login working fine with FOSUserBundle. I'm trying to get the SonataUserBundle working now with acl.

I have followed the instructions here https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/2.2/Resources/doc/reference/installation.rst but that resulted in an exception every time I tried to login:

```
You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.
```

This exception is thrown in both dev and prod. Similar problems from the web seem to involve an issue with the check_path when people try and introduce localisation. But none of the solutions put forward for those work for me.

This problem has totally exhausted me now, I simply can't figure out what to do. I've left several different attempted solutions in comments in the relevant source files, all relevant portions of these are below.

Any help gratefully received.

config.yml:

```
# FOS User Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Aleph2Omega\EducationBundle\Entity\User # Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User # previously


    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)

        sonata.block.service.text: # used to if you plan to use Sonata user routes
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

        # Some specific block from the SonataMediaBundle
        #sonata.media.block.media:
        #sonata.media.block.gallery:
        #sonata.media.block.feature_media:

sonata_media:
    # if you don't use default namespace configuration
    #class:
    #    media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    #    gallery: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    #    gallery_has_media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
            create:     false

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb
```

routing.yml:

```
sonata_user_security:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_security_1.xml"

sonata_user_resetting:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_resetting_1.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

sonata_user_profile:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_profile_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user_register:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_registration_1.xml"
    prefix: /register

sonata_user_change_password:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_change_password_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

gallery:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/gallery.xml'
    prefix: /media/gallery

media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /media

admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin
```

security.yml:

```
security.yml:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    # encoders:
    #     FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        # configuration prior to installation of SonataUserBundle
        # main:
        #     pattern: ^/
        #     form_login:
        #         provider: fos_userbundle
        #         csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        #     logout:       true
        #     anonymous:    true

        default:
            anonymous: ~

        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        # -> end custom configuration

        # default login area for standard users

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login # have also tried fos_user_security_login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check # have also tried fos_user_security_check
                failure_path:   null
                csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    acl:
        connection: default

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            # - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented
```

index.html.twig (problem occurs if I try and use either of the two path options fos_* or sonata_*):

```
{% extends 'Aleph2OmegaEducationBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Welcome to Aleph2Omega{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') -%}
        {{ include('Aleph2OmegaEducationBundle::menu.html.twig') }}
        Hello {{ app.user.username }}!
    {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_USER') -%}
        {{ include('Aleph2OmegaEducationBundle::menu.html.twig') }}
        Hello {{ app.user.username }}!
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">Login</a>
        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}">Register</a>
        <br>
        <a href="{{ path('sonata_user_security_login') }}">Test Sonata Login</a>
        <a href="{{ path('sonata_user_register') }}">Test Sonata Register</a>
    {%- endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

....MyBundle/Entity/User.php:

```
<?php
// src/A/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Aleph2Omega\EducationBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... solved my own problem.

It seems that under the firewalls configuration in security.yml by putting main before anything else the exception is no longer thrown.